# Resolving conflict on Manjaro update 2015-07-02

Tags: package-management, manjaro

I'm updating Manjaro (arclinux), but there are some errors that could not be resolved:

```
==> New package :   
extra/libgudev                   230-1                (required by colord)    
==> Continue upgrade ? [Y/n]    
==> [V]iew package detail   [M]anually select packages   
==> -------------------------------------------------- 
==> :: Starting full system upgrade...  
resolving dependencies...         
looking for conflicting packages...     
:: libgudev and libsystemd are in conflict. Remove libsystemd? [y/N] 
error: unresolvable package conflicts detected      
error: failed to prepare transaction (conflicting dependencies)   
:: libgudev and libsystemd are in conflict (libsystemd<221)
```

I've tried to remove `systemd`, `libsystemd`, `colord`, but it still can't be resolved, how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

add `IgnorePkg = colord` on `/etc/pacman.conf` solves this problem.

Comment: Not a solution, a workaround. You have incompatible versions of packages, either due to partial upgrades or some Manjaro-specific packaging issue.